# Azure source Dynamics with parameter error

Tags: azure, lookup, microsoft-dynamics, azure-data-factory

I have a simple pipeline where I look up a date from an Azure SQL DB table, and then try pass this to an XML query for Dynamics.

The lookup activity succeeds, output looks fine, I get an error message for the XML query which I have been trying to resolve for a long time without any success so far.

[This is the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y7W5.png)

And this is the XML query I am using in the source query:

```
<fetch>
<entity name="account" >
<all-attributes/>
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-after" value="@{activity('LookupAccountSQL').output.firstRow.modate}" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
```

The lookup activity name is LookupAccountSQL, and the SQL query is simple as below: (also debug runs successfully for this activity):

```
SELECT CAST(MAX(modifiedon)) as modate FROM dbo.account
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you not set activity('LookupAccountSQL').output.firstRow.modate value into variable and use it in fetchxml. clrealy fetchxml is not able to read this code. Fetchxml expects date value.  Also try to see if your activity('LookupAccountSQL').output.firstRow.modate returns datetime.

Comment: Whether the returned result of LookupAccountSQL activity contains any special characters?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Both were helpful, I found the solution - had to use formatDateTime on the output of the lookup activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments below my question I figured out the problem.
The lookup activity returns a datetime regardless of the fact that I use cast in the SQL query.

The solution is to put a formatDateTime() function on top in the Fetchxml.

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="account" >
   <all-attributes/>
    <filter type="and">
     <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-after" value="@{formatDateTime(activity('LookupAccountSQL').output.firstRow.modate,'yyyy-MM-dd')}" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
```